# Retrieve CREATE TABLE code of an already existing table?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Is there a way to do this?

In case the DBMS command history got cleaned or, in my case, when many ALTER TABLE were used in the course of time.

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: What's so hard looking this up in the manual?

Comment: You're right. I must learn this habit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is as simple as

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable;
```

This will include all the subsequent `ALTER TABLE` statements.  You cannot retrieve the table's *original* state.

Here is [the relevant documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html)